# How to set OMITTAG YES in XML file

Tags: xml, omittag

I have hundreds of files which don't compile into Microsoft Help Format because there are several minor XML syntax issues: `<dd>` without `</dd>` for example.

That's why I want to allow ignoring missing tags in XML so the XML files will pass the test of that conversion program (mshcMigrate Utility). But the question is: how to set OMITTAG to YES?

Comment: The whole point of XML is that you **must** have matching tags. `OMITTAG YES` in XML is an oxymoron.

Comment: Or more formally, XML is defined as an application of SGML that has OMITTAG NO in its concrete syntax. In other words, OMITTAG NO is part of what makes XML XML. With OMITTAG YES, it no longer is.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Setting `OMITTAG` to YES is an SGML feature that is not available in XML.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-sgml-xml.

BoltClock's comment is very much to the point. The tags must match; otherwise it's not XML.

Answer (score 1):

`OMITTAG` is an SGML feature.  XML does not have it.

If your originals are HTML files, and the markup in them is reasonably sane enough to pass [SGML validation](http://validator.w3.org/), then you might consider using [`osx`](http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/sx.htm) to convert them to XML (or "fully-tagged") format.